# Can't update to 11.04 from 10.10. Update Manager and Terminal not working?

Tags: 10.10, updates

I re-installed ubuntu 10.10 a few days ago after It messed up trying to upgrade to 11.04. I want to ultimately get it to 11.10, but now it won't even attempt an upgrade and I get this error message:

```
W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/maverick-updates/universe/binary-i386/Packages.gz  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/maverick-updates/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages.gz  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]

E: Some index files failed to download, they have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I have no idea what I should do next. I don't have a blank disc or a burner to download 11.10 manually. Since I'm new, I can't post the entire error code since there are so many hyperlinks.

Comment: Possible Duplicate: http://askubuntu.com/q/91815/44179

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your internet connection is not working properly so when you try to upgrade from terminal error message is there that "failed to fetch http:\*****".

There are many reasons for it. one of the reason could be that you are behind some proxy server. If so you can add proxy to work on your computer by

1. Go to system settings
2. find Network setting
3. in that you will find proxy server
4. chech for manual proxy
5. Insert your proxy settings (IP address  :  port no). add this proxy server for all type of connection like http, ftp, https
6. click on apply system wide

Now try upgrading your system by following command

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Comment: Sorry i took so long to reply. My internet is working fine! I'm using it now actually. So I don't think that's it.

Answer (score 0):

As you said you r new to this, it is worth mentioning that to install a latest ubuntu on to your system you will not require any blank disk or disk burner. Installing ubuntu is very simple what you will need is just a pen-drive.

1. Download latest version of ubuntu from here.(download .iso file)

   > [latest ubuntu version](http://releases.ubuntu.com/)
2. Next you will need a software which will make your pen-drive bootable.

   > [Download universal USB installer](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/)
3. Run Universal usb installer
   [image: Universal USB installer]
4. select version of your ubuntu
5. browse where you have downloaded ubuntu .iso file
6. Next select pen-drive and click on create.
   this will make your pendrive bootable to install ubuntu.

Change the Boot priorities from BIOS to first boot option as USB-drive. Boot from from pendrive, done with your installation.